# SQL Sub Query - data type mismatch error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to use a sub query to list student names and their course codes, for the students who have no timetabled lectures on Mondays from 2pm to 6pm

The SQL Query I have is

```
SELECT fname, surname, courseCode, dayReq, timeReq
FROM student, roomBooking
WHERE id IN
(SELECT sID
FROM studentReg
WHERE NOT dayReq = "Monday" AND timeReq BETWEEN "14:00:00" AND "18:00:00");
```

And when I try to execute this, I get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" which corresponds to the timeReq BETWEEN "14:00:00" AND "18:00:00" part.

The timeReq is Date/Time data type so I don't understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Hi Laura, can you please give us an example of your tables content (student, roomBooking)

Comment: Laura please provide us with the table structure or ddl of the table or something to relate with the query

Comment: Why are you doing a cross join on `student` and `roomBooking`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the DATEPART function to get the hour from timeReq and then just compare that with your interval, like this

```
SELECT fname, 
       surname, 
       coursecode, 
       dayreq, 
       timereq 
FROM   student, 
       roombooking 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT sid 
              FROM   studentreg 
              WHERE  NOT dayreq = "monday" 
                     AND Datepart("h", timereq) BETWEEN 14 AND 18)
```

Comment: It asks me to enter a parameter value for h when I try this

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to quote it, here is the documentation that I found for this function, maybe it helps too:http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php